# Shell script to only count consecutive days

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I was wondering how I would go around to do this.

This is an example of my output

```
Sun Aug 21 2016 03:00:00, BLAH
Mon Aug 22 2016 03:54:00, BLAH
Tue Aug 23 2016 04:22:11, BLAH
Thu Aug 25 2016 05:00:00, BLAH
```

Now what I would like to do is only count ***consecutive*** days so in the example above it should say `BLAH` appeared 3 times as they are after each other.

I have bash, awk, and sed available.

Comment: what about days that wrap to a new month? year? leap days?

Comment: here's a hint: with GNU date, you can do `date -d "Sun Aug 21 2016 03:00:00 1 day ago" "+%b %e"` to get `Aug 20`

Answer (score 1):

In AWK:

```
{
    sub(",", "", $0);  # kill first comma, thanks Thomas
    cmd="date -d \""$1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" 1 day ago\" \"+%b %e\"";
    cmd|getline dt;
    close(cmd);
    if (dt==prev && blah==substr($0, index($0, $6))) { times = times + 1 }
    else { print times" "line; times = 1 };
    prev=$2" "$3;
    blah=substr($0, index($0,$6));
    line=$0;
}
END { print times" "line }
```

Assuming we have this input inside a file called `blah.log`:

```
Sun Aug 21 2016 03:00:00, BLAH
Mon Aug 22 2016 03:54:00, BLAH
Tue Aug 23 2016 04:22:11, BLAH
Thu Aug 25 2016 05:00:00, BLAH
```

And the awk script in `consecutive.awk`, we can do:

```
$ awk -f consecutive.awk blah.log

3 Tue Aug 23 2016 04:22:11 BLAH
1 Thu Aug 25 2016 05:00:00 BLAH
```

Which gives the number of consecutive days as an extra column and prints the last date.  To get rid of the date in the output you can simply change `print times" "line` to `print times" "blah` (in the two places that is appears).

How does it work:

- Executes the date command to get Yesterday of the current line, thanks glenn jackman
- Compares against saved date from the previous line
- Increments a counter or prints
- Saves data from current line for next run

Notes:

- It is ugly (all AWK code is, get over it)
- Works well across any gaps (up to an entire year) because it uses `date`, but disregards timezones
- It considers that BLAH may be different on different lines and only matches BLAH occurrences against other BLAH occurrences.  If the file is not well ordered you may need to perform a `sort -t , -k 2`.
- If you need to consider for different values of BLAH you need GNU awk (thanks to the `substr` call).  Otherwise you can kill the `substr` call and the script will run on any posix awk.

Comment: It appears that you could dispense with `tr` by copying `$0` to a variable and chopping it up a little.  OP did not mention `tr` in the set of tools available.

Comment: @ThomasDickey - good point, I was stupid to worry about that `subst` in non-posix, but there is also plain `sub`, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This took more than I thought it would but the script below will do the job.

```
#!/bin/bash
str=" Sun Aug 21 2016 03:00:00, BLAH Mon Aug 22 2016 03:54:00, BLAH"
str+=" Tue Aug 23 2016 04:22:11, BLAH Thu Aug 25 2016 05:00:00, BLAH"
IFS='H' read -r -a inputArray <<< "$str"
days=(SunMon MonTue TueWed WedThu ThuFri FriSat SatSun)
count=1
found=0
lastOne=""
finalCount=0
for entry in "${inputArray[@]}"; do
   thisOne="${entry:1:3}"
   test="$lastOne$thisOne"
   for pair in "${days[@]}"; do
      if [ "$test" == "$pair" ]; then
         ((++count, ++found))
      fi
   done
   if [ ! $found ]; then count=1; else found=0; fi
   if [ $count -gt $finalCount ]; then
      finalCount=$count
   fi
   lastOne=$thisOne
done
echo "There were $finalCount BLAHs in a row."
```

Comment: That relies on having no gaps of a week or more.